# Replacing duplicate item in list through raw_input

Tags: python, list, duplicates, raw-input

Completely new to Python so bear with me.

I created a list through raw_input:

```
itemList = []
num = int (raw_input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range (num):
    listStr = raw_input("Enter an item: ")
    itemList.append (listStr)
```

Now I have to check if any item already exists, and if it does ask for another raw_input to add to list. I'm completely stumped. It's not looping with this; it just prints a anyway.I also then have to append new item to original list. Stumped.

```
itemList = []
num = int (raw_input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range (num):
    listStr = raw_input("Enter an item: ")
    itemList.append (listStr)
for a in itemList:
    if a in itemList :
        a = raw_input("Enter another number: ")
```

Comment: You are comparing strings and ints, so do this: `listStr = int(raw_input("Enter an item: "))`

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if an item already exists in the list? and if yes, ask for a different item to add?

Comment: listStr has to be a string. The amount of items in the list has to correspond with the int entered at num.

Comment: Farhan.K, exactly that.

Comment: @MrBloodDoll I've tested the code I've posted. Tell me if you face problems using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop to keep asking for input until an item is entered that isn't already in the list. This could be improved, but it should get you started:

```
itemList = []
num = int (raw_input("Enter a number: "))

for i in range (num):

    while True:
        listStr = raw_input("Enter an item: ")
        if listStr in itemList:
            print('That item is already in the list')
        else:
            itemList.append(listStr)
            break
```

Slightly better version:

```
itemList = []
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

for i in range(num):

    listStr = raw_input("Enter an item: ")

    while listStr in itemList:
        print("That item already exists")
        listStr = raw_input("Enter another number: ")

    itemList.append(listStr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code

```
itemList = []
num = int (raw_input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range (num):
    listStr = raw_input("Enter an item: ")
    itemList.append (listStr)
for idx in range(len(itemList)):
    # using a while ensures that if the value newly entered
    # is again present in the list, it again prompts for an input
    while itemList[idx] in itemList[:idx] or itemList[idx] in itemList[idx+1:] :
        a = raw_input("Enter a replacement for item {0}: ".format(itemList[idx]))
        itemList[idx] = a
```

Comment: `a = raw_input("Enter another number: ")` is not gonna do what he asks for... add `int`

Comment: @StamKaly I thought string inputs were acceptable too.

Comment: Sorry, that code should read: add another item, not number. Sorry, guys.

Comment: That was a bit much for a newbie like me, but thank you!